# Does browsers support Threads of Java Applets?

Tags: java, multithreading, applet

I have a Java Applet that records sound thru a web page.
The save-on-disk operation is made by an inner class which is a thread:

```
class saveThread extends Thread {

public void run() {
    AudioFileFormat.Type fileType = AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE;
    FileDialog fd = new FileDialog(new Frame(), "Save as WAVE", FileDialog.SAVE);
    fd.setFile("*.wav");
    fd.setVisible(true);
    String name = fd.getDirectory() + fd.getFile();
    File file = new File(name);

    try {
        byte audio[] = out.toByteArray();
        InputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(audio);
        final AudioFormat format = getFormat();
        final AudioInputStream ais = new AudioInputStream(input, format, audio.length / format.getFrameSize());
        AudioSystem.write(ais, fileType, file);
     } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
 }
}//End of inner class saveThread
```

The problem is the save on disk operation is not working when I execute the applet in a web page. But when I am executing directly the applet, it works like a charm, thats why I thought that maybe the problem is that browsers didnt support threads of applets.

Comment: _The problem is the save on disk operation is not working when I execute the applet in a web page._ That probably means your applet doesn't have permissions to write to disk.

Comment: how ? can you explain more please??

Comment: You can use an [access controller](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/AccessController.html) if your applet is called from untrusted source (i.e JavaScript).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JAVA Applet does support multi-threading. However, check that your applet is whither privileged or sandboxe. From [java applet documentation page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/security.html)

> It is recommended that you launch your applet using Java Network Launch Protocol (JNLP) to leverage expanded capabilities and improve user experience. See Deploying an Applet for step by step instructions on applet deployment.

And When launched by using JNLP, sandbox applets can also perform the following operations:

1. They can open, read, and save files on the client.
2. They can access the shared system-wide clipboard.
3. They can access printing functions.
4. They can store data on the client, decide how applets should be
   downloaded and cached, and much more.